# Start Tomcat's HTTP/HTTPS connector after all the applications are deployed

Tags: java, tomcat

**Problem:**

We have many applications in Tomcat and each one needs a lot of time to start.

During that time, if you make an HTTP request to the Tomcat port, it gets waiting till all the applications are fully started.

As we have a load balancer that only checks Tomcat TCP connections, it is not smart enough to discard that Tomcat instance.

**Wanted solution:**

I would like to know how to start Tomcat so it starts to listen HTTP requests only after all applications are fully deployed. In this way, the load balancer will notice that it is not possible to make a TCP connection and it will discard that Tomcat during that time.

Comment: How about tomcats hot deployment? See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html  Section "Deploying on a running Tomcat server" and following sections. This will save you time for the other applications.

Comment: Also see here for some tips https://stackoverflow.com/a/25878204/3021395

Comment: But in this case, if there is a request to one app that is not available yet, you get a 404 (because the load balancer I have only checks TCP connections).

Comment: Then maybe using an apache http with mod-proxy in front might help when distributing your applications onto different tomcats to have them isolated from each other.

Answer (score 0):

The tomcat wiki has a "how to" on this

[How do I make Tomcat startup faster?](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp)

In short:

- Web app configuration
- Remove unnecessary JARs
- Exclude JARs from scanning
- Entropy Source configuration
- Enable start of webapps in parallel with startStopThreads
- Tweak memory parameters
- Trim the config files as much as possible. XML parsing is not cheap. The less there is to parse - the faster things will go.
- Remove any web applications that you do not need. (So remove the all the web applications installed with tomcat)
- Make sure your code is not doing slow things. (Use a profiler)

Comment: In my case, the main reason is because when the application starts, it loads much data from database (during 4 minutes). We can make this lazily, but I'd prefer to play with the connectors of Tomcat if possible so we don't have to invest time coding it lazily.

Comment: How about having an extra thread for the initial database loading? Also you could try if the bindOnInit option (see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) will change something.